# What's behind INotifyPropertyChanged's PropertyChanged event handler? What is the message receiveing/processing mechanism?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

We all've been using `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It allows the controls being developed to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` events.

At the same time, the implementation of the interface is pretty simple and actually doesn't assume any explicit code for the `PropertyChanged` event handler. Here is a typical example of the implementation:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

It seems that WPF itself assigns an event handler to the declared member "`PropertyChanged`". So my question is what exactly WPF does with this member.

Maybe anybody could suggest a good article regarding the exact mechanisms behind `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I saw that many people on SO have already asked some similar questions but I haven't found any explicit answer.

Thanks!

Comment: INP is older than WPF. WPF just used an existing infrstructure for its bindings. The direct answer: [the Binding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). More interesting: [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by by "this control"?

Comment: @Blam : I deleted the whole sentence containing "this control" - it was rather confusing than clarifying the nature of my question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : Thanks a lot for the references! It seems that they indeed clarify a lot of the background for the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing smth but what makes you thinking that it's complex? Given that target implements INotifyPropertyChanged all needs to happen is a generic handler for that event.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interactively explore what is going on with INotifyPropertyChanged, I highly recommend going to Microsoft's new Reference Source site. I have been using it extensively to learn what is going on behind the scenes in .NET.

Here is a starting point for you:

[INotifyPropertyChanged (System)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/INotifyPropertyChanged.cs#fd4b42d7e29d53e5)

You'll also see a INotifyPropertyChanged2 implementation in PresentationFramework that you'll probably want to look through.

I hope this is helpful!